# footer social icons dont space out evenly when resized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

codepen below

https://codepen.io/nightcoder21/pen/BxwVdJ

HTML below

```
<section id="footer">
    <div class="container mb-1">
      <div class="row text-center text-xs-center text-sm-left text-md-left mb-2">



      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 mt-2 mt-sm-5">
          <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline social text-center">
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
        </hr>
      </div>  
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 mt-2 mt-sm-2 text-center text-white">
          <p>PC Handyman NZ - Small business / Home office IT solutions</p>
          <p class="h6">&copy All right Reversed.<a class="text-green ml-2" href="https://www.sunlimetech.com" target="_blank">PC Handyman 2018</a></p>
        </div>
        </hr>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </section>
```

I cant seem to get the 3 social icons in my footer to stay in proportion when resizing down to mobile size, I have got them looking perfect in all big size,

it looks distorted as per my picture[image]

how do i get them to line up?

Thanks

Comment: Please add html and css code

Comment: Can you expand on the HTML and CSS you are using for them, as well as the querie you are using? That way we would be able to help you with it. Thanks

Comment: You need to use a media query and adjust the margin/padding for the icons (margin-left: 5rem; padding-right: 3rem; padding-left: 3rem;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have a look at flexbox. There is a really nice tutorial [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

I've made a snippet that solves your problem:

```css
footer{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(250, 75, 83);
  width: 100%;
}
footer #icons{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
footer #icons i{
  font-size: 60px;
  font-style: normal;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  margin: 10px 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 520px){
  footer #icons{
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
  <footer>
    <div id="icons">
      <i>☼</i>
      <i>☂</i>
      <i>☃</i>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use media queries to handle style for smaller screen

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #footer ul.social li{
      padding: 3px 1rem;
    }
}
```